# Define common fields in multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, field, definition

Wondering if there is something in SQL Server to define a standard set of fields that will exist on most tables defined within an application.  As an example, I include a set of fields as an "update stamp and status" on all records.  These fields would be:
Field Name       Data Type
SYS_Valid        Boolean
SYS_Active       Boolean
SYS_Deleted      Boolean
SYS_CreatedAt    String           network computer id where record was first created
SYS_CreatedBy    String           network user-id who first created this record
SYS_CreatedOn    Date/Time        date/time when record was first created
SYS_CreatedVia   String           application routine used to create this record
SYS_UpdatedAt    String           network computer id where this record was last updated
SYS_UpdatedBy    String           network user-id who last updated this record
SYS_UpdatedOn    Date/Time        date/time when this record was last updated
SYS_UpdatedVia   String           application routine used to last update this record

I am just wondering if there is something like a user-defined "structure" that can be defined in the database once and then included in each table definition as a single "field".  The group of fields would be included with each record of each table.

Thank you for your help in this matter.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. And _rows_, not records.

Comment: short answer - no

Comment: If you're using SSMS it might help to use [script templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/template/templates-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: You can have this but it's down to you to implement it, there is no out-of-the-box solution. For example, in one system I work on we have audit columns such as CreatedDate, CreatedBy etc. I have a `dba` database and schema that has a procedure to find tables that are missing these audit columns and dynamically add to a table. It's not quite that simple but you get idea.

Comment: Well, that did not format the way I wanted ...
Thank you for the answers, that is what I thought may be true.  I guess I can make sure the same code exists in the Drop/Create T-SQL statements for the tables.