# SQL Define Relationship Involving a Common Column in Multiple Tables

Tags: sql

This is my first post so please forgive me if this has been answered elsewhere. There are sort of similar posts out there already such as [Define common fields in multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026991/define-common-fields-in-multiple-tables) but nothing that really relates to what I need as far as I can tell.

I have 3 tables. Two of the tables, **Clients** (PK: ClientId) and **Staff** (PK: StaffId), have very different data and numbers of columns - however they both have a Location (VARCHAR) column that stores a lat/long location. The third table is **Distances** in which I want to store the distances between any two places where each place could be either a client or staff.

To keep it simple, *my goal* is to be able to set it up in such a way that you could say construct the required relationships *using say a typical relationships editor where you can see the tables visually and the links between them* (i.e. create the constraints that enforce referential integrity).

I imagine that the columns in the **Distances** table will include the columns Place1Id, Place2Id and Dist, where Place1Id and Place2Id are the PKs of either the relevant client or staff table.

Clearly this is not enough because we can't yet tell if Place1Id refers to a school or client. I could add in another column into **Distances** called PlaceTypeId and have another table **PlaceTypes** containing a PlaceTypeId (say 1 for clients and 2 for staff) and say a VARCHAR Name (being either School or Client) - but this still wouldn't work in terms of being able to create the necessary relationships. For one, we haven't told the db anywhere that 1 refers to clients and 2 refers to staff.

Is there a way to achieve my goal elegantly (i.e. simple enough to be able to be done with say a visual relationships editor), or must I go down the path of something like storing the PlaceTypeId type in every row in **Clients** (which would all be 1), and in **Staff** (which would all be 2 and feels like replicating data unnecessarily), and then creating a unique key with via a combination of PlaceTypeId and ClientId or StaffId? (And then you can't do that with integers I assume because just adding them won't work of course...).

**ANSWER**
Ok - I believe I have the answer to this in case anyone else is wondering how to do this (credit to my friend Trav):
In the **Distances** table, include the columns ClientFromId, ClientToId, StaffFromId and StaffToId. That allows for client-client, client-staff, staff-client and staff-staff distances. Only 2 of these 4 columns will be populated of course.

Note: The distance from location 1 to location 2 is the same as location 2 to location 1 - however you still need 2 client IDs and 2 Staff IDs for when both the From and To entries are from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your ultimate goal is here, but before you start walking down the road of storing latitude and longitude as a string in a column, you should look into Geographic data extensions made available by certain RDBMS's.

Microsoft SQL Server supports the Geography datatype natively since at least 2012, and PostGRE has had the PostGIS extensions available for at least as long.  Both of these systems allow you to store geographic points as a lat/long as well as more complex polygons, and they have the built in functions to compute things like distance and area.  They also work almost seamlessly with ArcMap and other GIS systems to display the data.

As far as your data model goes, I believe you need a fourth table "Location"  The location would have a LocationID column and a Geography Column.  Then in your Staff and Client tables, instead of a Location column that contains a Lat/Long string, you would have a LocationID, which would be a foreign key to the location table.  Then your distances table (if it is still necessary since you are using a proper Geographic database) would just have two ID Columns and a distance column, but you can still join your location table to either the Staff or Client tables.  This data model also allows for the possibility that you could have a Staff record and a Client record at the same location.

If you really need to know whether a Location is a Staff record or a Client record without a join, you could add two boolean flags to the Location table, Staff and Client, but then you have to maintain those fields.

Edit:  It looks like MySQL now also supports the Geography datatype [since version 8.0](https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-with-spatial-data/)

Comment: BrianZ I am able to populate the distances with the Google Maps api, and using mySQL. The data as a lat/long string is fine for my purposes as that string pasted directly into Google Maps for example will result in a location as is.

Comment: Re: the table issue, yes distance is vital as I am paying my employees to travel per kilometre so I need distance. By adding the 2 extra columns of ids in the distances table, (so From and To for both Clients and Staff), I can create the relationships I need and it solves the issue of trying to work out what table the ids came from. If distance entry is client-client, then staff From and To will be NULL. 2 of the 4 will always be NULL, 2 will be populated. I am storing the distances as Google Maps api costs over a certain amount.

Comment: Are you trying to solve the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: Hey BrianZ, nothing that fancy. I have around 10 employees and 4 of them travel to clients. We see rural clients in the same trip to save on travel costs. I am developing a system to work out the travel charges and apportion them fairly among clients with weightings based on likely time taken and distance from the main city. The order we see them is based on common sense, it's overkill to do more. As part of this project I am also moving to using a database instead of spreadsheet tables. I'm the IT guy for my business, it's my background and I enjoy it. Yep, I'm a nerd!

Comment: By the way thank you for taking an interest and replying to me. Although your answer didn't solve what what I was asking, there is some other interesting info there and it never hurts to be aware of what is possible. For those who want an answer to this topic, specifically how to deal with say X tables all having a common column (location in my case), just make sure there are X columns in the other table (Distances in my case) so there is a 1:1 match with the ids of the X tables - and therefore you can create a relationship. So much easier than mucking around with PlaceTypes, extra tables etc